# Не работают зависимости в gradle

Tags: android, gradle

В *grable* пишу `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` не загружает, подчёркивает красным, также происходит со всеми android библиотеками.
Если подключать не андроид, например `compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'` все подключает отлично.

В чем проблема?

Ошибка:

> Dependency 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' not found

**build.gradle**:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp18"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {     jcenter() }

dependencies {


    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files ('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    //compile files ('libs/android-support-design.jar')

    //compile project('ParallaxScroll')
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    //./gradlew :ParallaxScroll:assembleDebug
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile files ('libs/android-support-v7-cardview.jar')
    compile files ('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
    //compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'

    }
```

Comment: Покажи весь файл gradle. P.S. не grable, а gradle

Comment: установлен ли Google Support Repository?

Answer (score 1):

В SDK Manager обновите до последних версий Android Support Repository

```
compile files ('libs/android-support-v7-cardview.jar')
compile files ('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
compile files ('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

Это убрать, вместо него:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

вместо `21.0.0` подставить соответствующую версия которая в вас в SDK Manager, сейчас актуальная `22.2.1`

Comment: Есть одна проблема, в силу некоторых обстоятельств я программирую в AIDE на андроид планшете. Поэтому SDK Manager не вариант.

Comment: @user186301 установите приложение из Google Play `SDK Manager`, оно создано специально для AIDE

Comment: Установил, теперь при подключении <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
 
</LinearLayou выбивает ошибку android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
07-27 22:03:31.057 7276 7276 E     AndroidRuntime

Comment: @user186301 Тема должна наследоваться от `Theme.AppCompat` а активити от `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: И что? У меня так и есть

Comment: @user186301 хмм, странно, можешь в вопрос добавить код активити в которой происходит ошибка и `styles.xml` ?